# Automatically Add HTML code in CKEDITOR 4

Tags: ckeditor, codemirror

I am using mailwizz for sending emails. Its using CKEDITOR 4 for create html template. When We add any contents in it, Its always getting inserted between  tag something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
//I want my all content here
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to do samething on my website but its not getting contents between body tag. When I see source in mailwizz ckeditor, it have always html starting and closing code but in my ckeditor its not.

I am attaching screenshot for the same.

[image: MailWizz Normal Mode]

This is normal mailwizz editor mode

[image: View Source Mode]

This is view source mode

In My Website, its View Source Mode looking like this
[image: My Website]

I have searched lot but not found any proper solution for the same. Let me know if anyone here can help me for the same.

Thanks!